# Code for generating PWM pulses in AtMega32U4

Tags: c

So here is my actual problem, I need to control the voltage of a FET using a PWM pin from an ATMEGA32U4. There are two signals. One signal turns the LED on and off, On for 1ms (1MHz) and off for 0.1ms. The second signal is the one which is a PWM which I want it to be a frequency of 50kHZ with a resolution of 30 of those pulses in that 50kHz time period within the 1ms ON time. Hope that makes sense. The AtMega is running at 16MHz clock.

So i am using two timers, One timer uses interrupts to control the LED and the other controls the PWM signal which goes to the FET.

I would really appreciate the help.

I have come up with this so far. please guide me.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


uint8_t tot_overflow;

void timer1_init()
{

TCCR1A |= (1 << CS01);      // set up timer with prescaler = 8
TCNT1 = 0;
TIMSK1 |= (1 << TOIE1);
sei();
tot_overflow = 0;
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
tot_overflow++;
}

int main(void)
{
DDRD |= (1 << 0);       //set Port D

timer1_init();

while(1)
{
    if (tot_overflow >= 250)  
    {
            PORTD ^= (1 << 0);    // toggles the led
            TCNT1 = 0;            // reset the counter
            tot_overflow = 0;     // reset the overflow counter

    }
}
}

void pwm_init()
{
DDRB = 1<<6;        // Generate 30kHz PWM signal on PB6

TC4H = (319) >> 8;  // Set TOP, write upper bits first.
OCR4B = (319) & 0xFF;

TCCR4A = (1<<COM4A1) | (1<<PWM4A);

TCCR4B = (1<<CS40);     // Start timer


TC4H = (320) >> 8;      // Set 100% duty cycle
OCR4A = (320) & 0xFF;

while(1)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean: You want the PWM running only during that 1ms while the LED is also on? But if you have 50kHz for 1ms, you would have 50 pulses, not 30.

Comment: Also, to what port are your FET and LED connected? The TCCR1A register does not have a CS01 bit. You want to set some of the COM1xx bits.

Comment: Yes I want the PWM running only during the 1ms while the LED is on. We doing servoing, so the pulses can vary. Yes ideally it would be 50 pulses but due to servoing I'm assuming the pulses may decrease. But yes 50 is ideal

Comment: The gate of the FET is connected to the PWM (PB6) and the LED is connected to the drain of the FET. Thank you

Comment: The tricky part is the LED should be on for 1ms and off for only 0.1ms. So i do not know how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use timers, based on your requirement. It basically uses two timers, which are both connected to the output pins for generating a PWM. One of them additionally triggers interrupts to turn on and off the other timer.

From the code you gave, it's not possible to turn your LED on for exactly 1ms. You connected it to the 8-bit timer, and there is no combination of clock divider and compare value, which gives exactly 1ms. You should connect your LED to 16-bit Timer/Counter1 instead.

NOTE: I have no 32u4 at hand, so can't test on real hardware. Consider that code "work in progress" and buggy.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void timer1_init()
{
    OCR0A = 69;    // Set TOP (maximum value that counter counts to)
    OCR0B = 63;    // Set duty cycle to ~10/11

    // Trigger interrupts when comparison is reached and at top
    TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0B) | ( 1 << TOIE0);
    // Set fast PWM on OC0B, turn pin low when counter reaches OCR0B
    TCCR0A = (1 << COM0B1) | (1 << WGM01) | (1 << WGM00);
    // Set fast PWM on OC0B, start timer with prescaler of 256
    TCCR0B = (1 << WGM02) | (1 << CS01);
}

void pwm_init()
{
    TC4H = (320) >> 8;  // Set TOP (maximum value that counter counts to)
    OCR4C = (320) & 0xFF;

    TC4H = (160) >> 8;  // Set 50% duty cycle
    OCR4B = (160) & 0xFF;

    TCCR4A = (1<<COM4B1) | (1<<PWM4B);  // Set fast PWM on OC4B
}

// This ISR is called when the timer reaches the top value
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    // Turn on PWM
    TCCR4B = (1 << CS40);
}

// This ISR is called when the timer reaches the compare value
ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
{
    // Turn off PWM
    TCCR4B = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = (1 << 0);   // Set pin PD0 as output (LED)
    DDRB = (1 << 6);   // Set pin PB6 as output (FET)

    pwm_init();
    timer1_init();

    sei();
}
```

Comment: I can work with this, I have the processor. Thank you

Comment: Let me know how it works, so we can fix the code if necessary or mark as correct.

Comment: timer 1 needs to be used but in the above code, the registers in use are for timer 0 namely OCR0A and TIMSK0 and so forth, is that correct?

Comment: From how I understand your code, there is something connected to PD0, which is OC0B. You say you want two signals, but for me it's still not completely clear which of them is connected to which pin.

Comment: PD0 is connected to the LED whose duty cycle is 90% and B6 is connected to the FET which is connected to the PWM output in the atmel.

Comment: And PD0 can be controlled with Timer 0, not with Timer 1. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: I tweaked the code and the PWM is working, still need to see the timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>

void timer1_init()
{
OCR1A = 319;    // Set TOP (maximum value that counter counts to) 
OCR1B = 290;    // Set duty cycle to ~10/11

// Trigger interrupts when comparison is reached and at top
TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1B) | ( 1 << TOIE1);
// Set fast PWM on OC0B, turn pin low when counter reaches OCR0B
TCCR1A = (1 << COM1B1) | (1 << WGM11) | (1 << WGM10);
// Set fast PWM on OC0B, start timer with prescaler of 8
TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS11);
}

// This ISR is called when the timer reaches the top value
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
// Turn on PWM
TCCR1B = (1 << CS10);
}

// This ISR is called when the timer reaches the compare value
ISR(TIMER1_COMPB_vect)
{
// Turn off PWM
TCCR1B = 0;
}

void pwm_init()
{
//define PC6 as output
DDRC |= (1 << 6);

//drive pins low
PORTC = 0x00;

//max counter value (50kHz)
ICR3 = 0x14;

//set duty to half
OCR3A = 0x0A;

//compare output mode:
TCCR3A = (1 << COM3A0) | (0 << COM3A0) | (0 << WGM31) | (0 << WGM30);

//prescaler/start timer:
TCCR3A = (1 << WGM33) | (0 << WGM12) | (0 << CS32) | (0 << CS31) | (1 << CS30);

}

int main(void)
{
timer1_init();
pwm_init();

while(1)
{
}
}
```